# How to Sum a series of rows in MYSQL from one Table, matching the info from another to get the result

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

```
SELECT table2.*, 
       (SELECT Sum(qtde) 
        FROM   table1 
        WHERE  table1.cnes = table2.cnes 
               AND table1.procedimento = table2.procedimento 
               AND table1.mes = table2.mes 
               AND table1.ano = table2.ano 
        GROUP  BY cnes, 
                  procedimento, 
                  ano, 
                  mes) AS soma 
FROM   table2
```

This code works great in Access.

I have two tables.

Table1 has the columns: `CNES, PROCEDIMENTO, MES, ANO, QTDE`

It may contain information like this (and I can't change this fact, I get the info from another software)

```
+------+--------------+-----+-----+------+
| CNES | PROCEDIMENTO | MES | ANO | QTDE |
+------+--------------+-----+-----+------+
| C1   | P1           | M1  | A1  |   12 |
| C1   | P1           | M1  | A1  |    3 |
| C1   | P1           | M1  | A1  |    5 |
| C1   | P2           | M1  | A1  |    4 |
| C1   | P2           | M1  | A1  |    4 |
| C1   | P2           | M1  | A1  |    3 |
| C1   | P3           | M1  | A1  |    4 |
| C2   | P2           | M1  | A1  |    5 |
| C2   | P2           | M1  | A1  |    4 |
| C2   | P1           | M1  | A1  |    3 |
+------+--------------+-----+-----+------+
```

QTDE = quantity of procedures (PROCEDIMENTO), from an hospital (CNES), done in a month (MES) and year (ANO)

So to know the quantity of procedures from one hospital to a single month i need to search all the rows and sum all the rows that's from that month...

Table2 has the columns: `CNES, PROCEDIMENTO, NOME, MES, ANO, META`

This table contains the number of procedures the hospital needs to perform in a month (META) and the actual name of the procedure (NOME. PROCEDIMENTO is a number but i store it as string[code])

So my query, that works in Access, would do this from that example above

Query1

```
+------+--------------+------+-----+-----+------+------------+
| CNES | PROCEDIMENTO | NOME | MES | ANO | META | SUM(QTDE)  |
+------+--------------+------+-----+-----+------+------------+
| C1   | P1           | N1   | M1  | A1  |   23 |         20 |
| C1   | P2           | N2   | M1  | A1  |   20 |         11 |
| C1   | P3           | N3   | M1  | A1  |   04 |          4 |
| C2   | P2           | N2   | M1  | A1  |   05 |          9 |
| C2   | P1           | N1   | M1  | A1  |   01 |          3 |
+------+--------------+------+-----+-----+------+------------+
```

If you take a closer look you will realize that the last column is the sum of quantity for that month so I can use that to see if the hospital did the quantity of procedures it was supposed to do in that month.

Besides that, and my query doesn't do that, but I wish it did... I would need another column to show the % (SUM(QTDE)/META). But I need to make %% that are over 100% to be just 100%... and I need to careful with divisions by zero problems....

Comment: What is your question?  What problems are you having?  And, which database are you using, Access or MySQL?

Comment: i want the code for MySQL the query that i have only work in Acess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works fine in MySQL 5.5.30:

```
select *, 
 if(meta = 0 or soma > meta, 100, (soma/meta)*100) Percent
from
(
 SELECT table2.*, 
   (SELECT Sum(qtde) 
    FROM   table1 
    WHERE  table1.cnes = table2.cnes 
           AND table1.procedimento = table2.procedimento 
           AND table1.mes = table2.mes 
           AND table1.ano = table2.ano 
    GROUP  BY cnes, 
              procedimento, 
              ano, 
              mes) AS soma
FROM   table2) TMP;
```

Comment: so, i need to fix the original code too so i can use it in MySQL. Becouse at MySQL that code just return NULL on the "SOMA" Column

Comment: Your original query runs just fine. You can see it here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c148/9

Comment: Thank you for your help it really does.
But i dont know why at Workbench keeps returning NULL to me... how i can i know whats hapenning and why?

Comment: Maybe your data contains NULLs or any values that causes the wrong behavior.

Comment: If i run this Query
SELECT Sum(producao.qtde)
        FROM   producao
       
        GROUP  BY producao.cnes,
                  producao.procedimento,
                  producao.ano,
                  producao.mes

Values returns just right. Anyway i can "watch" the process to identify the problem from the main query?

Comment: If you have no problem with that, maybe you can upload the data you are using to the SQL fiddle, and I'll take a look.

Comment: So, since workbench only showss the first 1000 rows i wanst able to see the problem. i Started to do queries by hospitals (CNES) and was able to find that those NULLS came from SUMs=0. 
Thank you for your help i didnt know that SQL Fiddle that really helped me to make sure code was OK and that the solution was somewhere else. =D